# How to safely and correctly destroy a mutex in Linux using pthread_mutex_destroy?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, mutex, race-condition

I read about [APUE 3rd](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321637739), 11.6.1 Mutexes, there is an example about lock and unlock a mutex in this chapter:

```
struct foo {
    int             f_count;
    pthread_mutex_t f_lock;
    int             f_id;
    /* ... more stuff here ... */
};

struct foo *
foo_alloc(int id) /* allocate the object */
{
    struct foo *fp;

    if ((fp = malloc(sizeof(struct foo))) != NULL) {
        fp->f_count = 1;
        fp->f_id = id;
        if (pthread_mutex_init(&fp->f_lock, NULL) != 0) {
            free(fp);
            return(NULL);
        }
        /* ... continue initialization ... */
    }
    return(fp);
}

void
foo_hold(struct foo *fp) /* add a reference to the object */
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&fp->f_lock);
    fp->f_count++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&fp->f_lock);
}

void
foo_rele(struct foo *fp) /* release a reference to the object */
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&fp->f_lock);
    if (--fp->f_count == 0) { /* last reference */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&fp->f_lock);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&fp->f_lock);
        free(fp);
    } else {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&fp->f_lock);
    }
}
```

In `foo_rele`, there is a race condition between `pthread_mutex_unlock` and `pthread_mutex_destroy`: **B thread** can call `pthread_mutex_lock` between `pthread_mutex_unlock` and `pthread_mutex_destroy` in **A thread** which will cause undefined behavior ("Attempting to destroy a locked mutex results in undefined behavior").

Am I right? If I'm right, then, how to make it work right or how to safely and correctly destroy a mutex in Linux using `pthread_mutex_destroy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The POSIX spec for `pthread_mutex_destroy()` says:

> It shall be safe to destroy an initialized mutex that is unlocked.

Which means that if thread B calls `pthread_mutex_unlock()` in the `else` clause of the `if` statement in `foo_rele()` then it's safe for thread A to call `pthread_mutex_destroy()` because it can only have gotten there after thread B's `pthread_mutex_unlock()` call has unlocked the mutex.

All of this is assuming that the reference counting is correct, such that some other thread cannot increment the count from 0 -> 1 after thread A has unlocked the mutex.  In other words, at the point where the refcount drops to 0, there can't be another thread that might possibly call `foo_hold()`.

APUE mentions this in the explanation right after the example code:

> In this example, we have ignored how threads ﬁnd an object before calling `foo_hold`. Even though the reference count is zero, it would be a  mistake  for `foo_rele` to free the object’s memory if another thread is blocked on the mutex in a call to `foo_hold`. We can avoid this problem by ensuring that the object can’t be found before freeing its memory. We’ll see how to do this in the examples that follow.

Comment: Could you please refer to the **11.6.2 Deadlock Avoidance** to check the sample code, I think threads can only increase the object reference by calling `foo_find`, not `foo_hold` directly, am I right?

Comment: Yes only `foo_find()` calls `foo_hold()`.  And when `foo_rele()`  finds that it's about to decrement a refcount to 0, it removes the item from the hash table while holding the mutexes, so no other thread can obtain a pointer to that `foo` object again.  Once that happens, the mutexes can be unlocked, the mutex in the `foo` object can be destroyed and the `foo` object itself be freed since nothing else can obtain that `foo` object anymore.

Comment: There are two version of sample code in chapter **11.6.2 Deadlock Avoidance**, in version one, code `foo_hold(fp);` in `foo_find` should be replaced with:
`pthread_mutex_lock(&fp->f_lock);
    fp->f_count++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&fp->f_lock);`
and function `foo_hold` should be removed.  
In version two, function `foo_hold` should just be removed, it is no use and dangerous on the other hand, users may misuse the interface, Right?

Comment: What you suggest is reasonable. But there can be legitimate uses for `foo_hold()`, too. One way to increment the refcount safely is to have  a policy that only a thread that already has a ref to the `foo` object be responsible to incrementing the refcount then give a pointer to another thread. If a thread that has a ref to the object is responsible for incrementing the refcount, then it's impossible for the refcount to go to zero during the increment operation. In other words, make it so only a thread that already has a ref can call `foo_hold()` to give a pointer to another thread.