# When to cleanup after socket deletion

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets

I am writing a small TCP sockets "library", and I ran into much trouble.

When something happens to the socket that causes it to be instantly closed and freed (regardless of background lingering, talking about user space here), which is only done within a locked mutex since the application I'm writing is multi-threaded, I need a way to tell all the other (potentially) waiting threads (on the same mutex) that want to do something with the socket: "I'm terribly sorry, but the socket has been destroyed and you cannot access it" so that they don't cause any segmentation fault or such.

The idea I had was: the mutex was part of the socket (socket = a structure that contains multiple things, including a mutex and a file descriptor) so I couldn't quite free the socket if other threads were waiting for it (undefined behavior), so the possible solution is to allocate the mutex, free the socket but not the mutex, set some flag (in the allocated memory) saying that the socket has been closed, and a counter so that the last thread waking up and getting notified that it cannot use the socket unlocks and destroys the mutex and frees the memory allocated. The mutex can still be accessed without segfault if we just store its pointer before acquiring the mutex (and the pointer won't ever change).

This solution has a fundamental problem though - what if between unlocking the mutex and freeing it by the last holder, the thread gets preempted and another one locks the mutex again (since you NEED to check socket-related stuff after you acquire the lock, so no way of knowing it got destroyed, unless you maybe use an atomic variable but then again, checking the atomic variable and locking the mutex as a whole are not an atomic operation). Or if you try to access the mutex on the already-freed socket. Undefined behavior emerges.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? I.e. how to destroy a socket so that other threads know about it to quit safely, and there are no race conditions? By quitting I mean aborting the socket function they were in, not cancelling or stopping the threads themselves.

Comment: What do you mean by "the mutex was part of the socket"? A socket is just a file descriptor, it doesn't contain a mutex.

Comment: If a socket has been closed and you try to use it, you get an error. As long as all the threads check for errors they shouldn't get any segmentation errors.

Comment: I just realized the problem: once the socket is closed, the fd can be reused for a new socket or file. So all the other threads need to forget the fd before any new fd's are allocated.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I meant the mutex is part of a structure that I identify as a socket. I will edit the Q to explain that more clearly.

Comment: How do you store the file descriptor of the socket? If it is a shared variable you can set it to -1 to indicate that the socket has been closed, and the other threads can check if the value is non-negative before trying to access it. I suggest to show some (pseudo-)code in the question to explain how the threads will interact using the socket and the mutex.

Comment: Checking for whether the socket is closed or not isn't really a problem. The problem is doing this in such a way that all current calls will return an error, but that I already have an idea for, which I explained in the post. But then again, some calls might be ongoing but the threads have been preempted, so the solution needs to include them as well, so that when they wake up, they know to not lock the mutex. Or, let them lock the mutex, but then again, this is kind of a loop. When do you stop and actually free the mutex?

Comment: This seems like a job for atomic reference counting.  You can close the socket and set the fd variable to −1 but not deallocate the wrapper object or the mutex until the reference count drops to zero.

Comment: Then before pthread_mutex_lock you need to check 2 atomic variables - one saying if the socket has been destroyed, second one expressing amount of threads waiting to acquire the mutex (eventually inc it). You can't check both of these atomically without another mutex, which again is not atomic with the proper socket mutex used to modify the socket. A bit tricky - would need to check all possibilities to see if there still is a race condition between 2 threads like that, where one thread is inside the socket mutex and detects the socket is dead, and the other one is before pthread_mutex_lock().

Comment: You are essentially asking this question: [_How to safely and correctly destroy a mutex in Linux using pthread\_mutex\_destroy?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345261/how-to-safely-and-correctly-destroy-a-mutex-in-linux-using-pthread-mutex-destroy)  If you can rely on manual reference counting with careful acquisition and careful release, and thereby safely destroy the mutex, then you can safely destroy the thing the mutex protects.

Comment: This seems like a good place to use `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @pilcrow The posts I was able to find (including yours and similar) explain well how to safely delete an object in case there are 2 threads. It does not explain how to do it when you have an unknown amount of threads and don't know when "the last access" will be. In other words, to solve my problem there would probably to be something like a callback function from the application stating it will never use the socket again, indicating to me that I can close the file descriptor and free allocated resources. I am looking for alternative solutions and ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a feasible solution of "auto-detecting" when the resources aren't in use (either some kind of a garbage collection, or a timeout since the last call made for that socket, e.g. if the application doesn't do anything with the socket for a minute after it closed, release its resources). That is why I decided to have some reference, look at other things dealing with the problem.

The first very obvious was the kernel itself. If the socket closes, the kernel informs the application of it happening, but only cleans up the socket once the application calls `close()`. I think it really is the best way of dealing with this problem, nonetheless it adds some additional responsibility to the application.