# In C language, do pthread_mutex_t need to be released after use?

Tags: c, linux, synchronization, pthreads, mutex

I use `pthread_mutex_t` in my program for thread synchronization control.
Do I need to do some finishing works when the `pthread_mutex_t` is no longer in use?
Or, can I do nothing?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Not a Linux expert, but I think you should (1) make sure it is unlocked, (2) call `pthread_mutex_destroy`: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/pthread_mutex_destroy.html

Comment: [`pthread_mutex_destroy`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/pthread_mutex_destroy.html) exists for a reason. Probably the one you're asking about. But it depends on what you mean by "in use". As in, "will never be used by another thread ever again" ? Yeah, destroy it after unlocking it.

Comment: @wohlstad *make sure it is unlocked*  That's likely just as bad as destroying an in-use mutex.  Trying to unlock a mutex not owned by the current thread is also [undefined behavior for a normal mutex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html).

Comment: @AndrewHenle that's correct. But the OP asked about how to handle a no-longer-used mutex (they didn't ask about other mutex issues), which my comment and answer addresses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mention that *"the pthread_mutex_t is no longer in use"*.
I assume you mean that you no longer need to use it, ever, in any of your threads.

**In this case:**

1. The `pthread_mutex_t` must be in the **unlocked state**.
2. You should call `pthread_mutex_destroy`.

The requirement for the mutex to be unlocked appears in the documentation for [`pthread_mutex_destroy`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/pthread_mutex_destroy.html):

> It shall be safe to destroy an initialized mutex that is unlocked.
> Attempting to destroy a locked mutex results in **undefined behavior**.

*(emphasis is mine)*

This post contains some more info about the proper usage of `pthread_mutex_destroy`:
[How to safely and correctly destroy a mutex in Linux using pthread_mutex_destroy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345261/how-to-safely-and-correctly-destroy-a-mutex-in-linux-using-pthread-mutex-destroy).

Comment: "Should" is a bit strong here.  You *can* destroy a mutex that is no longer needed, but I wouldn't elevate that to "should" except where the lifetime of the mutex object is going to end before the program terminates.  For example, it is pretty uncommon to explicitly destroy a file-scope mutex that was initialized via the static initializer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I understand there are special cases, but in general once you are done with a mutex I believe the best practice is to destroy it. I thought "Should" conveys this message. Feel free to edit my answer if you have a better phrasing.

Answer (score 2):

> I use `pthread_mutex_t` in my program for thread synchronization
> control.
>  Do I need to do some finishing works when the
> `pthread_mutex_t` is no longer in use?
>  Or, can I do nothing?

**TL;DR**: You do not *need* to do any cleanup.  In some cases you *should*, and in other cases it's a question of style.  And in some cases, the question is moot because it's not possible to recognize that a mutex is no longer in use.

---

The relevant sense of "no longer in use" here would be that the mutex is not currently locked by any thread (including the one that might perform cleanup), and there is no possibility that any thread will attempt to lock it in the future.  For this case, the `pthread_mutex_destroy()` function is available to release any resources that the mutex may be holding (not including the storage occupied by the mutex object itself).  In any other case, destroying the mutex puts your program at risk of exercising undefined behavior.

If a given mutex object has ever been initialized, including via the static initializer, and its lifetime ends at a point when it has not been destroyed since its last initialization, then the end of its lifetime must be assumed to leak resources.  But this is consequential only when the mutex's lifetime ends before the end of the program, because all resources belonging to a process are cleaned up by the OS when the process terminates.  In particular, it is *not* consequential in the common case of mutex objects declared at file scope in any translation unit.

Guidance, then:

- As a correctness matter, you *must* ensure that

  1. The lifetime of a mutex object does not end while it is still in use.
  2. No mutex is destroyed while it is still in use or after the end of its lifetime.
- As a practical matter, you *should* avoid consequential resource leaks, as they may ultimately lead to program failure and / or overall system stress from resource exhaustion.  In this context, that means using `pthread_mutex_destroy()` to clean up mutex objects having automatic, allocated, or thread storage duration before those objects' lifetimes end, when that occurs significantly before the end of the program overall.
- As a style matter, you *might* choose to apply a similar discipline to mutex objects having static storage duration -- perhaps only those initialized via `pthread_mutex_init()`, or perhaps including also those initialized via the static initializer macro.  I tend not to worry about these, myself, as there are rarely very many, and they rarely go out of use very much before the program is going to terminate anyway.
- As a style matter, you *should not* make heroic efforts or overly complicate your code to ensure that mutexes are explicitly destroyed when the program is terminating.  The OS is going to perform all necessary cleanup anyway, and any cleanup (or other) code that takes a lot of effort to write correctly in the first place is fertile ground for bugs and has high maintenance cost.

Finally, note well that there are cases when you can't even recognize before program termination that a given mutex is no longer in use.  For example, consider a program that declares a file-scope mutex used to synchronize the operations of several daemon threads.  It may well be that no thread in the system can determine whether all the (other) daemon threads have terminated, so as to know that the mutex is no longer in use, so there is no safe course but to avoid ever destroying it explicitly.